# Netty: Why HTTP upgrade uses HttpObjectAggregator

Tags: netty

I would like to understand why we need to buffer the whole HTTP request to perform an UPGRADE in HTTP. From what I understand only HTTP headers are required ?

I am fairly new to Netty so maybe there is another way to use it but from what I see it is not easy to UPGRADE when transferring a large file. Is that true ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're not obliged to use an aggregator. You could handle it yourself, so chunk by chunk (httpContent) once you get the header first.